# HQL : Adding colon seperated strings for multiple parameters to search with

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I am working on an Spring-MVC project in which I am using Hibernate as the ORM tool. One of the features of the project is that it can search for other users, by giving various parameters like country, city, etc. Now, I would like to pass multiple countries for the search. For that reason I am sending a `:` separated names of countries to the method.

As initially the method was only for a single country, I have modified the query to work in this order. Is this the right way to pass multiple parameters as the query is complex. Thank you.

```
@Override
public List<Student> addHostSearchHistory(HostSearchHistory hostSearchHistory, Long hostId) {

    String queryString = giveMeFormattedHostSearchString("AND",hostSearchHistory);

    Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);

    if (!(hostSearchHistory.getCity() == null)) {
        if (!(hostSearchHistory.getCity().equals(""))) {
            query.setParameter("city", "%"+hostSearchHistory.getCity().toUpperCase()+"%");
        }
    }
    List<Student> studentList = query.list();

    Query query1 = session.createQuery(giveMeFormattedHostSearchString("OR",hostSearchHistory));
    if (!(hostSearchHistory.getCity() == null)) {
        if (!(hostSearchHistory.getCity().equals(""))) {
            query1.setParameter("city", "%"+hostSearchHistory.getCity().toUpperCase()+"%");
        }
    }

}

private String giveMeFormattedHostSearchString(String clause, HostSearchHistory hostSearchHistory){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("from Student as s where ");

    if (!(hostSearchHistory.getCountry() == null)) {
        if (!(hostSearchHistory.getCountry().isEmpty())) {
            String[] countries = hostSearchHistory.getCountry().split(":");
            sb.append("(");
            for(String s : countries){
                sb.append(" ").append("upper(s.studentCountry) like ").append(s);
            }
            sb.append(")");


        }
    }
    if (!(hostSearchHistory.getCity() == null)) {
        if (!(hostSearchHistory.getCity().isEmpty())) {
            sb.append(" ").append(clause).append(" ").append("upper(s.city) like :city");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better less error-prone way to search for multiple countries.. Please note, I have only included 3 parameters to avoid clutter. Thank you.

Comment: Can you at least properly format your code? And please only leave related code in your question (No idea on how the studentList and driving license is related to your question)

Comment: @AdrianShum : Thank you. I have removed commented code, and driving license, just kept city for reference purpose to see how the query is structured. Thank you. :-)

Comment: just wonder, is it really hard to have the code properly indented?...

Comment: @AdrianShum : Was doing that, but found that you were already on it.. :-) Thank you. So, any ideas how can I provide multiple variables to one parameter in the query.

Comment: there is probably not much to choose.  One alternative is to use Criteria APIs which imho suit your situation.  Another a bit off-topic thing is, why would you pass a colon-separator string instead of using a list of string?  With a proper presentation of data is going to save you from troubles

Comment: @AdrianShum : I am saving them in DB as colon separated. I have not worked with Criteria API's. The problem is the project  simply has too many variables on which are hardly any processing is done, that's why I went this way.  They are used to just display information and rare updates.

Comment: Even you saved in DB like that, it is still not appropriate to have your DAO handle colon-separated string as it is something that the finder method shouldn't be aware of.  Another idea which I used before (but seems no similar solution publicly available) is to make a special syntax for HQL, and it goes through some kind of post-processor to construct the final query base on input data.

Comment: @AdrianShum : What would you suggest, create separate tables for all these variables and save them in that order in DB? After that, how does it effect the search, and how it's done then? Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking here.  `Student` to `Country` is simply many to one isn't it? I am simply saying for the thing passed into your repository for search should be in sensible presentation of data.  Even you are getting the criteria from somewhere else which it use comma-separate list, you should convert it to proper presentation and pass it into the repository for search

Comment: @AdrianShum : Okay, I will do that, but how do I modify the query to search for multiple parameters instead of one is my original question.

Comment: if it is simply a `foo.country in (:countryList)` then Hibernate, or Spring Data can help.  However for your case that you need to search list of countries using `LIKE`, you have to construct it manually and how to make the construction less error-prone, I have already given you idea in previous comments (using Criteria API, making a custom language, and even the "pass in list instead of using colon-separated-string" is part of the comment)

Comment: @AdrianShum : Thank you, I will check it out. If I have a doubt, I will ask. :-)

Comment: Do you really need to use "like" and "%" ?  Use "in" clause to make life easier.

Comment: @BlitheHuang : I was thinking the same thing, saving them in either upper-case or lowercase and directly searching the list with it.

Comment: I would do that too. And for general query generating logic, it's good to check spring data jpa. It's amazing that there is no need to write query generation logic for most cases.

Comment: @AdrianShum : please post an answer with `Criteria` for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Extracted based on comment in question)

If it is simply a `foo.country in (:countryList)` then Hibernate, or Spring Data can help. However for your case that you need to search list of countries using `LIKE`, you have to construct it manually.  Your way of construction (embedding the value directly in resulting query) is not preferable as it is error-prone and make your code open for SQL injection.

One of the ways to do proper query construction is to make use of Criteria API.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better extract the query generating logic from the dao. You can delegate it to another class or just create a method in that dao. However, when things get large, it's better to delegate it to another class.

By the way, spring data jpa has done the query generating logic for us. It can meet up almost all need in CRUD. You can take a look on it.

Comment: though I have been using Spring Data for quite some time and I loved it, what OP is trying to do seems not something supported by Spring Data (collection of values with LIKE clause)